# Defining struct members and matching string constants without repetition

Tags: c++, struct, macros, c-preprocessor

I am trying to define a `struct traits`, which contains bit-fields for different traits like so:

```c
struct traits
{
    unsigned char sometrait : 1;
    unsigned char someothertrait : 1;
    unsigned char anothertrait : 1;
};
```

To simplify defining new trait bit-fields, I'm using this macro:

```c
#define __deftrait(name) unsigned char name : 1;
```

I also need the string representations of these trait-bit fields, so I have another macro to define these string constants:

```c
#define __def_trait_str_repr(name) const char* _##name##_str = #name;
```

My `traits.h` is as follows:

```c
#define __deftrait(name) unsigned char name : 1;
#define __def_trait_str_repr(name) const char* _##name##_str = #name;

typedef struct traits
{
    __deftrait(sometrait)
    __deftrait(someothertrait)
    __deftrait(anothertrait)
    
} traits;

__def_trait_str_repr(sometrait)
__def_trait_str_repr(someothertrait)
__def_trait_str_repr(anothertrait)
```

I was wondering if I could make this whole trait bit-field defining process cleaner. The `__deftrait` macro could handle both defining the bit-field members, and their string representation.

However, I'm at my wits end here, because I suspect that just sticking the string representation macro at the end of the def macro would lead to a lot of string copies, and static strings can't be initialized inside a struct.

Thus, I was wondering if there is a way to define some kinda macro that would handle both, so the end result can be:

```c
typedef struct traits
{
    __magic(sometrait)
    __magic(someothertrait)
    __magic(anothertrait)   
} traits;
```

Comment: `__deftrait` is a reserved word.

Comment: as is `__magic`. And can you pick `C` or `C++` please.

Comment: C or C++, choose one. If latter, you could define the string as a static class member from the same macro.

Comment: Ah I'm using C++, and I can't use `std::string`, I have to use `const char*`s... @HolyBlackCat

Comment: I didn't suggest `std::string`. I suggested moving `const char* _##name##_str = #name;` inside the class and making it `static`.

Comment: ... [like this](https://godbolt.org/z/1o81M7zWM)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do is a common problem, and the following solution is often used for implementing "magic enums".

```cpp
#define LIST(...) \
  __VA_ARGS__(a) \
  __VA_ARGS__(b) \
  __VA_ARGS__(c)

#define DEFINE_MEMBER(...) unsigned char __VA_ARGS__ : 1;
#define STRINGIZE(...) const char * const __VA_ARGS__##_str = #__VA_ARGS__;

typedef struct traits
{
    LIST(DEFINE_MEMBER) /* expands to:
    unsigned char a : 1;
    unsigned char b : 1;
    unsigned char c : 1; */
} traits;

#undef E
#define E(...) const char * const __VA_ARGS__##_str = #__VA_ARGS__;

LIST(STRINGIZE) /* expands to
const char * const a_str = "a";
const char * const b_str = "b";
const char * const c_str = "c"; */

#undef STRINGISZE
#undef DEFINE_MEMBER
#undef LIST
```

The basic idea is that we define a `LIST` macro at the top, which lists the symbols and all their properties. In this case, it's just the name.

We can then expand this list with `LIST(DEFINE_MEMBER)` to define all our bit-field members, and with `LIST(STRINGIZE)` to define our string constants.

*Note: Avoid the use of leading underscores in global scope. Names with leading underscores are reserved for the implementation.*

### C++-specific notes

The above solution works in both C and C++.
In C++, you are free to omit `typedef`, can can just write `struct traits { ... };`

Also, you can simplify this solution by declaring the string constants as static data members. [@TedLyngmo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7582247/ted-lyngmo) has [provided an example](https://godbolt.org/z/1o81M7zWM).

#### C++11 or greater

Add `constexpr` to the string constants, since they are compile-time constants.

#### C++17 or greater

Add `inline constexpr` to give the constants inline linkage. By default, they would have internal linkage, which can cause some unusual odr-violations. Furthermore, even if you can't use `std::string`, you could use `std::string_view` instead of a `char*`, potentially.

Comment: Using external definitions in macro is confusing. Pass macro callback name as  an argument to list `#define LIST(E)`. Makes the code much more static and easier to follow - `#undef E` makes it confusing, there is no clear connection between `LIST` and `E` macro, `LIST` expanding to different things is suprising.

Comment: @KamilCuk it is surprising and confusing, but that's just an innate property of macros. `a_str` and the like have internal linkage, so they're not external, if that's what you mean. `LIST` has to expand to different things because that's how we avoid repetition. I'm not sure what you mean by `LIST(E)`, what would that expand to?

Comment: Like so https://godbolt.org/z/zEsWEqMvz . Related https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/process/coding-style.html#macros-enums-and-rtl part `macros that depend on having a local variable with a magic name:`. Here, the local variable is `E` macro definition. Overall, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro example 2.

Comment: @KamilCuk thanks, I didn't realize that you can create higher-order functions in macros like that. I've used your idea now, but with `__VA_ARGS__` for `LIST`.